# Emulating JS's optional chaining operator in C++

Tags: c++, preprocessor

There is [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in JavaScript. It starts to be appealing to have analogue of it in C++, when one deals with codebase, where are a plenty of `struct`-s codegened (JSON-serializable bodies of requests and responses to/from C++ backend microservices). These are a chains or trees of compositions (`struct A { B b; C c; };`) and indirections (`struct A { std::(unique_ptr|shared_ptr|optional|std::add_(pointer|lvalue_reference)_t|etc)<B> b; }`) of some others.

It is possible to emulate imaginary `operator ?.` in "functional style":

```
namespace utils {

namespace impl {

template <typename T>
using IsPointerLike =
    decltype(std::declval<T&>() ? std::addressof(*std::declval<T&&>())
                                : nullptr);

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool kIsPointerLike = meta::kIsDetected<IsPointerLike, T>;

}  // namespace impl

template <typename Leaf>
constexpr auto* GetIf(Leaf&& leaf) {
  if constexpr (impl::kIsPointerLike<Leaf>) {
    return leaf ? utils::GetIf(*std::forward<Leaf>(leaf)) : nullptr;
  } else {
    return std::addressof(std::forward<Leaf>(leaf));
  }
}

template <typename Root, typename Head, typename... Tail>
constexpr auto* GetIf(Root&& root, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail) {
  if constexpr (impl::kIsPointerLike<Root>) {
    return root ? utils::GetIf(*std::forward<Root>(root),
                               std::forward<Head>(head),
                               std::forward<Tail>(tail)...)
                : nullptr;
  } else {
    return utils::GetIf(
        std::invoke(std::forward<Head>(head), std::forward<Root>(root)),
        std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
  }
}

}  // namespace utils
```

where `meta::kIsDetected` is implementation detail having intuitively straightforward semantics (implements "detection idiom").

When one dealt with type names and field names that are short, then all looks fine:

```
struct C { std::shared_ptr<int> d; };
struct B { C c; };
struct A { std::optional<B> b; };
A a{...};
if (int* d = utils::GetIf(a, &A::b, &B::c, &C::d)) {
    std::cout << *d << "\n";
}
```

But things starts to be not so appealing when longer names comes into play:

```
utils::GetIf(request, &PaymentServiceRequest::full_price, &Prices::fees, &Fees::tax)
```

Is it possible to emulate optional chaining operator `request?.full_price?.fees?.tax` in C++ in (at least) functional-style way, like `OPT_DEREF(request, full_price, fees, tax)`? Can it be implemented using preprocessor function-like macros (possible with G++/clang++ extensions)? Possible non-variadic (i.e. w/o using of `__ARGS__`, `##__ARGS__`, etc).

The main goal it to be free from explicit or implicit (`decltype(expr)`) mentioning of any type names in notation.

Comment: There is the "elvis operator" that is a non-standard compiler extension supported by quite a few compilers: it's akin to a ternary `?:` with the middle expression omitted (though it truly is a binary operator). The left-hand side is your value if "truthy", and the right-hand side is your "falsey" value.

Comment: I guess you can do that using std::optional

Comment: @folibis seems what you mean is to convert to series of inlet `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`, that have to be dereferenced in a way like `a.value().get().b.value.get()...`? It is not a solution

Comment: @Rogue do you mean `!a?:!a->b?:!a->b->c?:!a->b->c->d?:&*a->b->c->d`? It is hard to write + quadratic length of a final notation

Comment: Perhaps in tandem with a macro, but I'm not aware of a good way to slice a string in that manner. The "crappiest way" would be a try/catch, and the more difficult way would likely be a design refactor such that you aren't travelling down such a long reference chain to begin with.

Comment: @Rogue while you calculate full chain of producing optionals you already can throw on some step. Anyways the matter of dispute is how to invent a macro magic to get a pairs `(a, b), (b, c), (c, d)` for `F(a, b, c, d)` call.

Comment: If you're okay with the functional approach `F(a, b, c, d)`, then you could just have your macro do the replacement with the ternaries/elvis/whatever. `!a ?: !a->b ?: !a->b->c ...` might be terrible to read/write, but it can very well be produced by a macro. I do think long-term this solution will hurt more than it will help.

Comment: @Rogue resulting compexity is also quadratic. N^2/2 number of dereferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the macro OPTIONAL_CHAINING we are using in our production code base.
The arguments to the macro can be (and typically are) method calls.
It is based on immediate lambda expressions.
This implementation has a `defRet` value, that can be simply nothing, for the default value when a `nullptr` is found somewhere in the chain execution.

```
#define OPTIONAL_CHAINING(...) PASTE_TOKEN(OPTIONAL_CHAINING, VA_ARGS_NUM(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)

// The other macros below should be considered private implementation details.
#define OPTIONAL_CHAINING1(defRet, obj, call1) [&]()->decltype((obj)->call1){ \
    auto v1 = obj; if(!v1) return defRet; return v1->call1; }()

#define OPTIONAL_CHAINING2(defRet, obj, call1, call2) [&]()->decltype((obj)->call1->call2){ \
    auto v1 = obj;        if(!v1) return defRet; \
    auto v2 = v1->call1;  if(!v2) return defRet; \
    return v2->call2; }()

#define OPTIONAL_CHAINING3(defRet, obj, call1, call2, call3) [&]()->decltype((obj)->call1->call2->call3){ \
    auto v1 = obj;        if(!v1) return defRet; \
    auto v2 = v1->call1;  if(!v2) return defRet; \
    auto v3 = v2->call2;  if(!v3) return defRet; \
    return v3->call3; }()

#define OPTIONAL_CHAINING4(defRet, obj, call1, call2, call3, call4) [&]()->decltype((obj)->call1->call2->call3->call4){ \
    auto v1 = obj;        if(!v1) return defRet; \
    auto v2 = v1->call1;  if(!v2) return defRet; \
    auto v3 = v2->call2;  if(!v3) return defRet; \
    auto v4 = v3->call3;  if(!v4) return defRet; \
    return v4->call4; }()

#define VA_ARGS_NUM_(P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, Pn, ...) Pn
#define VA_ARGS_NUM(...) VA_ARGS_NUM_(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define PASTE_TOKEN(x,y) PASTE_TOKEN_(x,y)
#define PASTE_TOKEN_(x,y) x ## y
```

Comment: It is sad, but maybe this way to solve is the best in SOTA C++) (CPP)

Comment: I was interested to see if somebody would find a better solution than mine (so I upvoted the question). It does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a macro that does this for you:

```
#define OPT_DEREF1(object, f0) (object) ? object->f0 : NULL
#define OPT_DEREF2(object, f0, f1) (object && object->f0) ? object->f0->f1 : NULL
#define OPT_DEREF3(object, f0, f1, f2) (object && object->f0 && object->f0->f1) ? object->f0->f1->f2 : NULL
```

You can do some macro magic if you want a single, overloaded macro.

```
#define opt_deref_impl2(object, f0) (object) ? object->f0 : NULL
#define opt_deref_impl3(object, f0, f1) (object && object->f0) ? object->f0->f1 : NULL
#define opt_deref_impl4(object, f0, f1, f2) (object && object->f0 && object->f0->f1) ? object->f0->f1->f2 : NULL

#define POP_10TH_ARG(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, argN, ...) argN
#define VA_ARGS_COUNT(...)  POP_10TH_ARG(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

#define CONCATENATE(x)  opt_deref_impl ## x
#define SELECT_FUNCTION(postfix) CONCATENATE(postfix)
#define OVERLOAD_FUNCTION(...) SELECT_FUNCTION(VA_ARGS_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)

#define OPT_DEREF(...) OVERLOAD_FUNCTION(__VA_ARGS__)


#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
  const char* x;
};

struct B {
    const char* x;
    A* a;
};

struct C {
    const char* x;
    B* b;
};



int main() {
    A a = A{"a"};
    B b = B{"b", &a};
    C c = C{"c", &b};
    
    C* object = &c;
    
    printf("%s\n", OPT_DEREF(object, x));
    printf("%s\n", OPT_DEREF(object, b, x));
    printf("%s\n", OPT_DEREF(object, b, a, x));
    
}
```

Comment: You said singular, but I see plural.

Comment: @TomilovAnatoliy Yes, you need to create one for each argument count, or do some macro magic.

Comment: I want a beautiful solution. It is possible I know.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no recursive macros in C++ they are emulated: recursion depth is limited by some arbitrary constant (256 in the following snippet).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// FOR_EACH from https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html

#define PARENS ()

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(EXPAND4(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND4(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define FOR_EACH(macro, ...)                                    \
  __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(FOR_EACH_HELPER(macro, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define FOR_EACH_HELPER(macro, a1, ...)                         \
  macro(a1)                                                     \
  __VA_OPT__(FOR_EACH_AGAIN PARENS (macro, __VA_ARGS__))
#define FOR_EACH_AGAIN() FOR_EACH_HELPER

#define MEMBER_ACCESS(member) , \
[](auto* clazz) constexpr -> auto* \
{ \
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(clazz->member)>>) { \
        return clazz ? clazz->member : nullptr; \
    } else { \
        return clazz ? &clazz->member : nullptr; \
    } \
}

template<typename Prev, typename Curr, typename... Next>
constexpr auto* compose(Prev* prev, Curr&& curr, Next&&... next)
{
    auto* clazz = curr(prev);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(next) == 0) {
        return clazz;
    } else {
        return compose(clazz, std::forward<Next>(next)...);
    }
}

#define OPT_DEREF(first, ...) \
    compose(&first FOR_EACH(MEMBER_ACCESS, __VA_ARGS__))

#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    {
        struct Z { int t = 123; };
        struct Y { Z z; };
        struct X { Y y; } x;
        int * t = OPT_DEREF(x, y, z, t);
        assert(&x.y.z.t == t);
    }
    {
        int t = 123;
        struct Z { int * t = nullptr; } z{&t};
        struct Y { Z * z = nullptr; } y{&z};
        struct X { Y * y = nullptr; } x{&y};
        int * pt = OPT_DEREF(x, y, z, t);
        assert(&t == pt);
    }
    {
        int t = 123;
        struct Z { int * t = nullptr; } z{&t};
        struct Y { Z * z = nullptr; } y{};
        struct X { Y * y = nullptr; } x{&y};
        int * pt = OPT_DEREF(x, y, z, t);
        assert(!pt);
    }
}
```

There is FOR_EACH from [https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/va-opt.html](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/va-opt.html).
Above snippet not handles pointer-like first name. Also there is only lvalue references and plain pointers handled, but it is simple to make it more generic.